# jQuery Find and Filter

Tags: jquery, filter, find, substring, indexof

I've got this HTML fragment:

```
<body id='mydoc'>

<table id='mytab'>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>My String is simple</td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.parsequery.js"></script>
<script>

var obj = $('#mydoc').find('td').filter(function(){
   return ($.text(this).indexOf('My String') != -1)       
   });

alert(obj.length);
for (i=0; i<obj.length; i++)
{
        alert($(obj[i]).html());
}
</script>
```

and the javascript alert returns 2 objects. I don't know why this happens.
How can I get the cell containing "My String is simple" only?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<td>My String is simple</td>` is wrapped inside `<td><table><tr><td>My String is simple</td><tr></table></td>`, so both are being returned.

You could either search for an exact text match:

```
filter(function(){ return ($(this).text() == 'My String') })
```

or search for a cell that doesn't contain a cell:

```
filter(function(){ return ($(this).text().indexOf('My String') != -1 && $(this).html().indexOf('<td>') == -1) })
```

There are a few other options, but it all depends on how you want to filter the selection down.

Comment: This solution doesn't work I'm getting a javascript error saying that the method is not supported ($.html(this))

Comment: Change it to `$(this).html().indexOf...` then, should fix it :) Answer updated.

Comment: Yep it does.However, what if the structure is more nested? Like this:<table id='mytab'>
 <tr>
    <td>
 
 <table>
  <tr>
       <td>
    <table><tr><td>
    My String is simple
    </td></tr></table>
   </td>
  <tr>
 </table>


    </td>
  </tr>
</table>   In that case it'll return 2 items!!!   I want an unambiguous way to retrieve just my cell!

Comment: Give it a try, it will. It'll only returns cells which (a) contain "My string" and (b) don't contain another `<td>`

Comment: You are right, the thing is that it's case sensitive. I had to type <TD> to make it work. Thank you.

Comment: Purely as a side-note, your HTML tags should be lowercase - it won't be XHTML compliant unless you do. Glad it works though :)

Comment: Hi Joe, to play it safer, I just want to add that $(this) is actually a cell and doesn't contain anything other than my text (i.e. its nodeType==3) what should I do?

Comment: That's fine, the `.html()` of a text node will return the text node. As that text node doesn't contain the text `<td>`, it'll be returned as a match.

Comment: Joe, I've tried the code above in a more complex HTML fragment and it returns 2 elements (whilst it should return 1 cell only). These are the elements returned:  ************************************************<table class="urPgHTTbl" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td class="urPgHTTxt">My String is simple</td></tr></tbody></table><img class="urPgHTImg">*************************My String is simple   and, honestly, I don't know why this happens!!! Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: Your string contains `<td class="...">` which doesn't match `<td>`, so it fails the test. An easy solution is to change it to look for `</td>` instead of `<td>`, which should result in the correct result every time.

Comment: Yes Joe, you are right, it works with </td>. However it looks a little too artificial to me. I thought there'd be a better way to filter out nodes whose immediate child is not a text? If that was possible, I'd have fixed all my issues...in fact only the cell containing the text "My String is simple" would be returned because that's the only one to contain, as immediate child, text only. Any idea? This is just to better understand this selector concept in jQuery. In fact your solution works for all purposes and intents!

Comment: Can't give you a good answer there I'm afraid. I'm a graduate of the "working is better than perfect" school :P

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your answers and your efforts! Ciao

Answer (score 1):

It happens because it matches the `<td>` element in the table around it as well as the inner `<td>` element.

Change the "filter" line to this:

```
var obj = $('#mydoc').find('td').filter(function()
{
    return $(this).find('td').length == 0 ? true : false;
}
```

...to find the innermost `<td>` - to make sure it also contains 'My String' try this:

```
var obj = $('#mydoc').find('td').filter(function()
{
    return (
      $(this).find('td').length == 0 && ($.text(this).indexOf('My String') != -1)
    ) ? true : false
}
```

Comment: This solution works but I can't use it. In fact, the problem is more complex. What if the document is like this?

Comment: <body id='mydoc'>

<table id='mytab'>
 <tr>
    <td>
 
 <table>
  <tr>
       <td>
    <table><tr><td>
    My String is simple
    </td></tr></table>
   </td>
  <tr>
 </table>


    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

Comment: Ok, I've modified my answer to find the innermost td rather than the second. It goes through each td in the document and ignores any that contain another td. I added the second one in case you also wanted to find that string as well. (Edit: just noticed another implementation of basically the same thing in another answer - but my implementation isn't case sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table td').children('td').filter(function(){
   return ($.text(this).indexOf('My String') != -1)       
});
```